# C++ operator overload =

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I can't understand last part of this code.
What actually this copy() function do? Why deleted memory data can be copied to m_array?

```
void IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& other) {
    int* array = new int[other.m_size];

    delete[] m_array;
    m_array = array;
    m_size = other.m_size;
    copy(other.m_array, other.m_array + m_size, m_array);
```

Comment: @Mogsdad Array of type delete. Are you serious? Consider deleting your comment...

Comment: Thank you, I removed some part of my codes by mistake.

Comment: Classic example of how NOT to overload `operator=`. What happens in self-assignment?

Comment: The copy function is `std::copy`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy.  Also, this is a horribly coded function -- it does not check for self assignment, and the assignment operator should be returning a reference to `IntArray`, (`*this`), not `void`.  Where did you get this implementation of an assignment operator from?

Comment: Thanks will look into it self-assignment. this is a course material.

Comment: Jinkies! Ezerk, questioning more of the course material is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It is an assignment operator overload for class `IntArray`. This class has a dynamic array `m_array` as member variable. So intention is to copy data from an object  `other` of type `IntArray` to current object. Before copying we need to clean up the data and its allocated memory in the current object's `m_array` at first. So we are calling `delete [] m_array`. Next we need to resize the current objects `m_array` to match with the size of the `other` object's `m_array` of object array. So doing a heap allocation in first line and assigned that heap location to `m_array` of current object. In the last copy statement, copying data from `other` object's `m_array` to current object's `m_array`.

Comment: I think 'delete [] m_array' means release the memory of other object. So I assumed 'other.m_array' does not have any data. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Ezerk I fine tuned what I intended in answer. Thanks for the note!

Comment: Answer to second part of your question, your assumption is incorrect. It may or may not have data.

Comment: Thanks your modification.  still my question is why last part of code `copy(other.m_array, other.m_array + m_size, m_array);` works? Once data in other objects cleaned up then why it can be copied to current object's `m_array`?

Comment: @Ezerk *Once data in other objects cleaned up* -- I guess you are misunderstanding what an assignment operator is supposed to do.  The "other object" is *not* getting cleaned up.  It is the *current* object that needs to release its memory, allocate new memory, and then copy the "other object's" data to the new memory.

Comment: Thats make sense. I am totally misunderstand what an assignment operator is ... thank you so much your help!